# Regex returns with incorrect value

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a function with a regex that can decide if my string value is correct or not. It should be `true`, if the string begins with lower or uppercase alphabetical characters or underscore. If it begins with any others, the function must return `false`.

My test input is something like this: `".dasfh"`

The expressions, what I tried to use: `[_a-zA-Z]`..., `[:alpha:]`..., but both of them returned true.

I tried a bit easier task also:

`"Hadfg"` where the expression is `[a-z]`...: returns `true`

BUT

`"hadfg"` where the expression is `[A-Z]`...: returns `false`

Could anybody help me to understand this behaviour?

Comment: What do you need to do? Validate? Note JS does not support POSIX character classes like `[:alpha:]`. Try [`/^[a-z_]/i`](https://regex101.com/r/fX2iX4/2) if a validated string must *begin with lower or uppercase alphabetical characters or underscore*.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/iH6kV3/1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to match the first character in the string to be something in particular, this means you have to tell regex that it has to be the first character in the string.

The regex engine just tries to find *any* match in the entire string.

All you're telling it with `[a-z]` is "find me a lowercase character anywhere in the string". This means that:

`"Hadfg"` will equal true because it can find a, d, f or g as a match.
`"HADFG"` will equal false because there are no lowercase letters.

the same will happen for `"hADFG"` when matched with `[A-Z]` for instance, it will be able to find an A, D, F or G as a match whereas `"hadfg"` will return false because there is no uppercase character.

What you are looking for here is `^` in your regex, it is a special kind of modifier that indicates "start of line"

So when you apply this to your regex it will look like this: `/^[a-z]/`.
The regex on the previous line basically says "from the start of the string, is the first character following up a lowercase a-z?"

Try it out and you'll see.

For your solution you'd need `/^[_a-zA-Z]/` to check if the first character is an _, a-z or A-Z character.

For reference, you can find cheatsheets within these tools (and test your regexes with it ofcourse!)

1. [Regexr](http://regexr.com/) - My personal favorite (Uses your browsers JS regex engine)
2. [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) - A Ruby regex tester
3. [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) - A Python / PCRE / PHP / JavaScript

And for a reference or tutorial (I'd recommend reading from start to finish if you want to start understanding regexp and how they work) theres [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Regex is never easy and be careful with what you do with it, it's a powerful but sometimes ugly beast to deal with :)

**PS**

I see you tagged your question as [email-validation](/questions/tagged/email-validation) so I'll add a little bonus regex that validates the *minimum* requirements for an *email address* to be absolutely correct, I use this one personally:

`.+@.+\..{2,}`

which when broken up, looks like this:

`.+` - one or more of any character
`@` - followed by a literal @ character
`.+` - one or more of any character
`\.` - followed by a literal . character
`.{2,}` - two or more of any character

Optionally you could replace `{2,}` with a `+` to make it one or more but this would allow a [TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) with 1 character.

To see a RFC email-regex at work check [this link](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html).
When I look at that regex I basically just want to cry in a corner somewhere, there are definitely things you cannot do in an email address that my regex doesn't address but at least it makes sure it's something that **looks like** it's *e-mailable* anyways, if a new user decides to fill in some bull that's not my problem anymore and I wouldn't want to force them to change that 1 character just because the huge regex doesn't agree with it either.

Comment: Thanks for your fast and understandable answer. It works correctly.

Comment: @Zse glad I could help, have fun developing :)